# Implementing Data into my javascript from a website

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, search

I'm not very experienced with gathering data from a website, but I was wondering how I could utilize data from:
http://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json.
I'm pretty sure this is an array and I would like to implement a loop in the data and then find an item in the array with a name "example" and gather other information about that item. Could you guys help me with some helpful resources or explain to me how the whole process works. Thanks!

Also, when I do this:

```
var products =[];
$.getJSON("http://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json",function(data){
  products=data.products_and_categories.Bags;
});
```

products should become'"Bags":[{"name":"Supreme®/LACOSTE Shoulder Bag","id":171383,"image_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/150220/ca/j2E28zL8Qjw.jpg","image_url_hi":"//assets.supremenewyork.com/150220/rc/j2E28zL8Qjw.jpg","price":11000,"sale_price":0,"new_item":true,"position":12,"category_name":"Bags"},...(with stuff in btw){"name":"Waist Bag","id":171192,"image_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/148435/ca/YJ3QsO4FWDw.jpg","image_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/148435/rc/YJ3QsO4FWDw.jpg","price":8800,"sale_price":0,"new_item":false,"position":30,"category_name":"Bags"}]
and when i do products[0].id, i should get 171383 right

Comment: this is what you are looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: could you help me with an example of fetching. Would fetch('http://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json')and then add some code after that. cold you help me with the code after because im not sure how to translate the array from the link to the array in my js

Comment: sorry if my question was unclear, but the main purpose of this was to be able to automatically "fetch" data from the link and be able to access and search the array in my js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to make AJAX calls to fetch json data.

```
var products =[];
$.getJSON("http://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json",function(data){
  products=data.products_and_categories.Bags;
});
```

Then you can write a function, which takes the name of an item or the item id as a parameter, which then gives out the information you want.

Useful ressources: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/
https://jquery.com/

Comment: What would that function look like? would i just like use a for loop and say if getjson=="user input name"? And also could you be a little more specific please?

Comment: Pay attention to where i pull data from the json file from. It would be rather like if(products[index].name == "user input")

Comment: oh ok thanks and also instead of .name, i could also use .id or other stuff right? Thanks!